# root directory when we create new ftp connection in godaddy

Tags: php, ftp

My question is that what is root directory of my document. I have created new ftp connection from godaddy . if I will create my own public_html directory and when I open from the Ip address its this message :

```
If you're the site owner, log in to launch this site
If you are a visitor, check back soon.
```

Comment: public_html and www both act as a root directory, you dont have to create hosting providers will provide those folders to you

Comment: @zan yes i have added my file index.html  in public_html and also give the permission but its not open

Answer (score 0):

"what is root directory of my document" doesn't really make sense as a question, and you haven't specified what type of hosting you have at GoDaddy.  I'll assume you are using Economy Shared Linux Hosting and mean to ask "what is the root directory for my domain".  The answer is: You decide this when you set up the domain.  In the hosting control panel there is a link called "Domains".  When you click that it will show you your hosted domains along with their root directories.  If you want to change the root directory for a domain, you can do it in there.  You can also add addition domains and root directories from this menu item